# code which one should I change to throw button and instantly displays my listview without having to click a button

Tags: android, json, listview

code which one should I change to throw button and instantly displays my listview without having to click a button

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnLoadFeed; <<<<<------------- Which should I remove associated with this code?
TextView textViewFeedUrl; 
ListView listViewFeed;

List<FeedItem> listFeedItems;
ListAdapter adapterFeed;

String myFeed = "http://temfilm.blogspot.co.id/feeds/posts/default?alt=json";
//String myFeed = "http://arduino-er.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json";
//String myFeed = "http://helloraspberrypi.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json";
//String myFeed = "http://photo-er.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnLoadFeed = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loadfeed);
    textViewFeedUrl = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.feedurl);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_feed);
    listViewFeed = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listviewfeed);

    listFeedItems = new ArrayList<>();
    adapterFeed = new ArrayAdapter<FeedItem>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listFeedItems);
    listViewFeed.setAdapter(adapterFeed);

    btnLoadFeed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textViewFeedUrl.setText(myFeed);
            new JsonTask(listFeedItems, listViewFeed).execute(myFeed);
        }
    });
}

/*
JsonTask:
AsyncTask to download and parse JSON Feed of blogspot in background
 */
private class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, FeedItem, String> {

    List<FeedItem> jsonTaskList;
    ListView jsonTaskListView;

    public JsonTask(List<FeedItem> targetList, ListView targetListView) {
        super();
        jsonTaskList = targetList;
        jsonTaskListView = targetListView;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        jsonTaskList.clear();
        jsonTaskListView.invalidateViews();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            final String queryResult = sendQuery(params[0]);
            parseQueryResult(queryResult);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            final String eString = e.toString();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            eString,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            final String eString = e.toString();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            eString,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(FeedItem... values) {
        FeedItem newItem = values[0];
        jsonTaskList.add(newItem);
        jsonTaskListView.invalidateViews();
    }

    private String sendQuery(String query) throws IOException {
        String queryReturn = "";
        URL queryURL = new URL(query);

        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)queryURL.openConnection();

        if(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader =
                    new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    inputStreamReader, 8192);
            String line = null;
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                queryReturn += line;
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
        }


        return queryReturn;
    }

    private void parseQueryResult(String json) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        final JSONObject jsonObject_feed = jsonObject.getJSONObject("feed");
        final JSONArray jsonArray_entry = jsonObject_feed.getJSONArray("entry");

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(jsonArray_entry == null){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "jsonArray_entry == null",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            String.valueOf(jsonArray_entry.length()),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    for(int i=0; i<jsonArray_entry.length(); i++){
                        try {
                            JSONObject thisEntry = (JSONObject) jsonArray_entry.get(i);
                            JSONObject thisEntryTitle = thisEntry.getJSONObject("title");
                            String thisEntryTitleString = thisEntryTitle.getString("$t");

                            JSONArray jsonArray_EntryLink = thisEntry.getJSONArray("link");

                            //search for the link element with rel="alternate"
                            //I assume it's one and only one element with rel="alternate",
                            //and its href hold the link to the page
                            for(int j=0; j<jsonArray_EntryLink.length(); j++){
                                JSONObject thisLink = (JSONObject) jsonArray_EntryLink.get(j);
                                try{
                                    String thisLinkRel = thisLink.getString("rel");
                                    if(thisLinkRel.equals("alternate")){
                                        try{
                                            String thisLinkHref = thisLink.getString("href");
                                            FeedItem thisElement = new FeedItem(
                                                    thisEntryTitleString.toString(),
                                                    thisLinkHref);
                                            publishProgress(thisElement);
                                            break;
                                        }catch (JSONException e){
                                            //no such mapping exists
                                        }
                                    }
                                }catch (JSONException e){
                                    //no such mapping exists
                                }

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Just hide it using `btnLoadFeed.setVisibility(View.GONE);` and when want to show use `View.VISIBLE`

Comment: I'm a Beginner, I mean I do not understand you